# Не получается работать с библиотекой AndroidDrawer

Tags: android, java

Хочу добавить в приложение выдвижное меню, качаю библиотеку [здесь](https://bitbucket.org/verdigo/drawer/overview).

В эклипсе библиотеке `AndroidDrawer` добавляю библиотеку `ActionBarSherlock`. Все ок, ошибок нет.

Своему проекту добавляю библиотеку `AndroidDrawer`.

Пишу код как указано в примере:

```
import pl.verdigo.libraries.drawer.Drawer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainMenu extends Activity {

    Drawer mDrawer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mDrawer = Drawer.createLeftDrawer(this, R.layout.drawer_content);
        mDrawer.init();

        mDrawer.show();
    }

}
```

Ну и `layout` `drawer_content`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

Вылетает с ошибкой:

```
12-20 12:37:39.147: E/AndroidRuntime(6378): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ActionBarView can only be used with android:layout_width="match_parent" (or fill_parent)

12-20 12:37:39.147: E/AndroidRuntime(6378):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)

12-20 12:37:39.147: E/AndroidRuntime(6378):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
```

Подскажите что я сделал не так?

Answer (score 1):

Вам не нужен  ActionBarSherlock, воспользуйтесь  [Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) - в сапорте запилили и фрагменты, и actionbar, и боковую навигацию.
 Старые проекты вроде  ActionBarSherlock прекращают поддерживать, не стоит начинать новый проект с ними.